# Switch local variable compile error

Tags: java, switch-statement, declaration

Why is this a compile error? Java cannot reach both declarations of `bar`.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class SwitchTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int foo = r.nextInt(2);

    switch(foo) {
    case 0:
      int bar = r.nextInt(10);
      System.out.println(bar);
      break;
    case 1:
      int bar = r.nextInt(10) + 10; // Doesn't compile!!
      System.out.println(bar);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're both in the same lexical scope, which is different from execution reachability.

Put braces around the code inside each `case` and it will work.

Comment: +1, but: *"Put braces around the code inside each case and it will work."* Or better yet, *don't do that*.

Comment: For those who aren't sure of the definition of "lexical scope", is it the same thing as a grouping of braces?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Why not?

Answer (score 3):

You could declare bar outside the scope too

```
import java.util.Random;

public class SwitchTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int foo = r.nextInt(2);

    int bar;    //bar is out of the switch scope

    switch(foo) {
    case 0:
      bar = r.nextInt(10);
      System.out.println(bar);
      break;
    case 1:
      bar = r.nextInt(10) + 10;
      System.out.println(bar);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I know how to fix it, I just want to know why it happens.

Comment: Well if you know how to fix, you should know _you can't declare a variable two times in the same scope_ that's why it happens. Anyway I think this is more readable so I posted the code.